# Create custom formula from Mathematical numbers and operators

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

I need to create a customized formula generated from Numbers (1-100) & Operators (+,-,*,/). The precedence of operation has to be dynamic. User can choose the numbers/operators one-by-one. But how to arrange the precedence for where to put the Brackets and all to make it a valid expression. For Example :

1. (21*430)-17+((45/5)+135)+243-16
2. ((97+74)+242-(169+13)*4)/76-21+(36*4012)

We need to take numbers/operators as inputs but the order/type can be dynamic & random. The only limitation is in an expression the total numbers used is fixed (here in 1. 8 numbers & 2. 10 numbers).

Please suggest a feasible solution to this.

Comment: Can you please add an example.

Comment: If you just wanted final output assuming your expression is correct then directly use [NSExpression](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/). And if want each and every operator and operand different then you need to do parsing.

Comment: Yes, all needs to be different or can say as per chosen by the user. But how to set the precedence order using brackets. This is something that cannot be put anywhere. We will need to ask user at relevant places. And the formula is not fixed. It can be anything but by using only 10 numbers. Any suggestions?

Comment: We can only ask a user to choose a number operand or an operator. But the question is how to manage the next operands with precedence using brackets or not.

Comment: I would suggest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm, after converting infix notation to postfix, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation, but a bit modified. When an operator is pushed onto stack, you're calculating it and pushing it back to stack. Instead of that, you can create a string, and push it back as an operand.